# Python : array tuple extraction

Tags: python

```
results=[('uid=alex,class=zenth',{'age':['12'],'uidnumber':['12AC']}),('uid=beth,class=nenth',{'age':['22'],'uidnumber':['13SD']})]
```

Like this it will have many tuples, how can I extract only UIDs so I want alex, beth and anyother uid in the results array

I can do

```
uid_val_list=[]
for _,val in enumerate(results):   
     list_vals=val[0].split(",")
     uid_val=list_vals[0].split("=")[1]
     uid_val_list.append(uid_val)
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
import re

results = [('uid=alex,class=zenth', {'age': ['12'], 'uidnumber': ['12AC']}), ('uid=beth,class=nenth', {'age': ['22'], 'uidnumber': ['13SD']})]

c = re.compile('uid=(?P<uid>.+?),')

uid_val_list = [c.search(result[0]).group('uid') for result in results]
print(uid_val_list)
```

1. make it compiled before search may speed up.
2. except for list comprehension, you can also use map() if you like.

Comment: what if I have more field in the uid ' '..so if [('uid=alex,class=zenth, item=22333,numid=1a@23', {......})] and rest can be same..I think with this the above solution won't work. Because I tried on the actual result set and it is returning :  'alex,class=zenth, item=22333,numid=1a@23'

Comment: I tried doing result=re.search(r"\w+,\b", val[0]), it serves the purpose I guess but not so neat and append ',' at the end

Comment: I modify the code and it should work correctly now. (add ? in the end of the regex string to make it ungreedy)

Comment: can you explain the regex a little? It worked, thanks.

Comment: Sure. The regex string 'uid=(?P<uid>.+?),' means try to match string like 'uid=xxx,',  and xxx can be anything by using '.+?', it means match more than one word, and '?' make it ungreedy. The part '?P<uid>' is group match which will be returned later. For detail about regex, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "[re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)" module:

```
import re

results=[('uid=alex,class=zenth',{'age':['12'],'uidnumber':['12AC']}),('uid=beth,class=nenth',{'age':['22'],'uidnumber':['13SD']})]

uid_val_list=[]
for _,val in enumerate(results):
    result = re.search("uid=(.*),",val[0])
    uid_val_list.append(result.group(1))
```

Output:

```
>>> uid_val_list

['alex', 'beth']
```

The command `re.search()` lets you scan a string and return the desired portion of it. In this case, it is scanning for `uid=(.*),` which means:

*Find the string in between the string 'uid=' and the string ','*

Which happens to be the names you're looking for

Note: There's really nothing 'wrong' at all with your current method.

Comment: but can I say using re makes it more optimized since results can have many tuples and then creating 2 lists is little un-optimized?

Comment: @user3089927 If you use the `re.compile()` method suggested by @flycee, then yes, using `re` would make your code 26.46969% faster than your current approach (I timed it), thus making it the better method. And we're talking about millisecond differences. Also, since you are using tuples, you can't get what you want without making new lists/dictionaries because tuples are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ast.literal_eval to convert the string from the tuple into a dict:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html

```
ast.literal_eval('uid=alex,class=zenth')
{'uid': 'alex', 'class': 'zenth'}
```

Then you can access the dict value easily

```
string_list = [i[0] for i in results]
uid_class_dict = [ast.literal_eval(string) for string in string_list]
uids = [uid_class.uid for uid_class in uid_class_dict ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple and short list comprehension:

```
item.split(',')[0].split('=')[-1] for item in results
```

---

```
>>> [item[0].split(',')[0].split('=')[-1] for item in results]
['alex', 'beth']
>>>
```